# How to compare time series between subjects?

Tags: time-series, arima

I require some help with analysing data that one of my students collected.

The student measured the surface temperature of two parts of the body every minute for an hour.

Here's an example of one of the trials: [image]

She performed the experiment at three different temperatures (EXPERIMENT = 25°C, 30°C, 35°C), for each temperature the experiment was repeated three times (TRIALNUMBER = 1, 2, 3) and in total she had four individuals (INDIVIDUAL = P1, P2, P3, P4).

The dataset looks like this (for each line we collected the temperature data as shown above):
[image]

We want to find out:

a) Is there a temperature difference between the two body parts throughout the experiment? The hypothesis would be that there is no temperature difference between the two body parts over time.
b) Does the temperature difference between the two body parts differ between temperature and/or subject (trial can be seen as a random effect)? Again, we hypothesize that the temperature difference does not differ between temperatures or subjects.

I'm not sure how to go about this. The dataset contains time series, but I'm not sure how to compare these between groups and taking random effects into account.

Any help will be much appreciated!